# how set ConstraintLayout layout_weight programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

when I set layout_weight of LinearLayout, I coded like this.

```
layoutParams = 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0, 1f)
```

but the ConstraintLayout doesn't have weight parameter.
ConstraintLayoutParams just have width, height like this.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
)
```

Why doesn't the constraintLayout have layout_weight parameter?
and how can I set layout_weight of constraintlayout programmatically?

i want to put constraintlayout in linearlayout horizontally.

so i must set layout_weight of constraintLayout but i can't

Comment: It will depend on what you want it to do. Layout weight can do a lot of things. From the question it is not clear which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

`ConstraintLayout` does not work the same way `LinearLayout` does. You can throw any view into `LinearLayout` and it will place where it has space with regard to its `orientation`.

`ConstraintLayout` is based on `Constraints`. You need to tell each view what his constraints are.

If you want simply the view to be the parents' whole height? Well, that is defined as the top of the view you want to add is going to be constrained to the top of the parent. The same with the bottom of the view, which will be constrained to the bottom of the parent.

```
val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
val view: View = findViewById(R.id.view);
view.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            0, // This has ConstraintLayout common with weights, leaving the height 0
)
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

// TOP of the view to the TOP of parent_layout
constraintSet.connect(
    R.id.view, // startID
    ConstraintSet.TOP, // startSide 
    R.id.parent_layout, // endID
    ConstraintSet.TOP, // endSide
);

// BOTTOM of the view to the BOTTOM of parent_layout
constraintSet.connect(
    R.id.view, // startID
    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, // startSide 
    R.id.parent_layout, // endID
    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, // endSide
);

constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```